# ArcGIS Oracle bulk update using spatial join

Tags: sql, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I am trying make bulk update the table using a spatial join which has millions of records,
updating the ID from Parcels layer to the Park (Points) layer using Oracle SQL query, I used geometry functions `ST_Within`, `ST_Contains`, `ST_Intercects`, but all are taking hours to complete sometime not even completing.

I used below queries :

```sql
MERGE INTO ejarunits v USING (
    SELECT f.OBJECTID
         , a.SUBDIVISIONPARCEL_UNIFIED_ID 
    FROM   subdivisionparcelboundary a
         , ejarunits f 
    WHERE  sde.st_intersects(a.shape,f.shape)=1
) w ON ( v.objectid = w.objectid ) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET v.SUBDIVISIONPARCEL_UNIFIED_ID = w.SUBDIVISIONPARCEL_UNIFIED_ID;
```

-2nd query--------------------

```sql
UPDATE ejarunits f 
SET f.SUBDIVISIONPARCEL_UNIFIED_ID = (
        SELECT  SUBDIVISIONPARCEL_UNIFIED_ID 
        FROM (
            SELECT a.SUBDIVISIONPARCEL_UNIFIED_ID
            FROM   subdivisionparcelboundary a
                 , ejarunits g
            WHERE sde.st_within(g.shape,a.shape)=1
        ) z 
        WHERE f.OBJECTID = z.objectid
);
```

What is best and fast update query to update the bulk data using the spatial joining?

Comment: You have a tag for ArcGIS Desktop but make no mention of how this relates to either ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap so I'm going to remove that.  On the other hand you seem to be using ArcSDE so I'll add a tag for Enterprise Geodatabase.

Comment: That's some gnarly SQL code. I use virtual tables in UPDATE all the time in PostgreSQL/PostGIS, but *never* in a subquery. If you work on getting the SELECT performant, then the UPDATE is just `UPDATE table t SET field = vt.field FROM ({virtual_table_select}) vt WHERE t.objectid = vt.objectid`, which should be plenty fast. This might be more appropriate over in [dba.se].